# Counting odd, even & negative numbers in an array using Java Inheritance & Polymorphism

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, counting

[ClassDiagram]![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3L2f.jpg)

I am a novice learning inheritance and polymorphism in Java. I came across this problem that I have been trying to solve. I seem to be getting the expected answers right, but whenever I run the Tests, I get errors for IsEven and IsNegative. What might I be doing wrong in relation to inheritance and polymorphism that is causing these errors even though my codes in the individual classes are working well?

**Here is the question:**
The picture above  shows the relationship between the classes.
Consider an array of integers as below:

```
int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13}
```

1. Complete the method named count(int[] a) in the class Count. The method should return the number of positive numbers in the array. Thus count(a) should return 7 (not counting the 2 negative numbers and 0).
2. On examining your code for count (your solution to part-a), you will see a test similar to this: if (a[i]>0) {...}. If we were to now ask you to modify the count method so that it counted the number of negative numbers, it would be trivial: All that you would have to do is change the greater-than comparison operator (“>”) to the less-than operator (“<”). If we were to ask you to modify the count method to count the number of even numbers (whether positive or negative) then you would modify your code to have a test along the following lines: if (isEven(a[i])) {...}. Similarly, you could change your code for other types of counting (prime numbers, numbers greater than 10, etc). Note that in each case we can do any type of counting we like but we need to edit the code for the count method. This is a simple example of enhancing the functionality of existing code. For this part of the question, you will write Java code that allows you to enhance the counting functionality without modifying the code of existing methods. You will do this using the power of inheritance and polymorphism.

a.  Complete the method countIF that is similar to your implementation of count (from the earlier part of this question) but takes as parameter an object that implements the appropriate test. The signature of countIF is as below:

```
int countIF( int[] a, Predicate p)
```

Complete the class Predicate which has just one method that returns true if the parameter is greater than 0:

```
boolean test(int x){ ... ? ... }
```

When countIF is invoked with a Predicate object, the behaviour will be as before: Your code will count the number of integers greater than 0 (i.e., the execution would return 7).
b.  Now complete the two classes (IsNegative and IsEven) as subclasses of the Predicate class to help you count negative (IsNegative) and even numbers (IsEven).

```
class IsNegative extends Predicate {...}
class IsEven extends Predicate {...}
```

Note: IsNegative and IsEven classes should have a test method with the same signature as before: `test(int x)`. Once these classes have been written you will be able to pass in an instance of the appropriate class to countIF to do the testing we need:

```
1.  countIF( a, new IsNegative() )
2.  countIF( a, new IsEven() )
```

The first call above would return 2 for our array. The second call would return 4.

**Below are the classes given:**

```
public class Count
{
   int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};

   public int count( int[] a) {
       return -1; // Note to Student: Delete this line. Write your implementation here.
    }

    public int countIF( int[] a, Predicate p) {
      return -1; // Note to Student: Delete this line. Write your implementation here.
    }

}

public class Predicate
{
    public boolean test(int x) {
        return true; // Note to Student: Delete this line. Write your implementation here.
    }
}

public class IsEven extends Predicate
{
   public boolean test( int x) {
       return true; // Note to Student: Delete this line. Write your implementation here.
    }
}

public class IsNegative extends Predicate
{
    public boolean test( int x) {
        return true; // Note to Student: Delete this line. Write your implementation here.
    }
}

public class CountTest extends junit.framework.TestCase
{
    public void test_count() {
        Count c = new Count();
        int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};
        assertEquals( c.count(a), 7);
    }

    public void test_countIF_predicate() {
        Count c = new Count();
        int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};
        assertEquals( c.countIF(a, new Predicate()), 7);
    }

    public void test_countIF_even() {
        Count c = new Count();
        int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};
        assertEquals( c.countIF(a, new IsEven()), 4);
    }

    public void test_countIF_negative() {
        Count c = new Count();
        int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};
        assertEquals( c.countIF(a, new IsNegative()), 2);
    }
 }
```

**HERE ARE MY IMPLEMENTATIONS OF THE CLASSES. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG IN TERMS OF INHERITANCE AND POLYMORPHISM?**

```
public class Count
{
   int[] a = {5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -5, 7, 11, 6, 13};
    int positive =0;

     public int count( int[] a) {
     for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
           if(a[i]>0){
               positive+=1;
            }
        }
        return positive;

   }

    public int countIF( int[] a, Predicate p) {
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(a[i]>0){
                positive+=1;

            }
        }
        return positive;
    }
public class Predicate
{
    public boolean test(int x) {
        int positive=0;
        if(x>0){
            return true;
         }else{
            return false;
        }


    }

}

public class Predicate
{
    public boolean test(int x) {
        int positive=0;
        if(x>0){
            return true;
         }else{
            return false;
        }


    }


}

public class IsEven extends Predicate
{
   public boolean test( int x) {
      if((x%2)==0){
          return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

      public int countIF( int[] a) {
       int even =0;
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
          if((a[i]%2)==0){
            even +=1;

            }

        }
         return even;
    }
}

public class IsNegative extends Predicate
{
    public boolean test( int x) {
        if(x<0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

     public int countIF( int[] a) {
       int negative =0;
       //super(x);
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
          if(a[i]<0){
            negative +=1;

            }

        }
         return negative;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue I see, is your `Predicate` sub-classes don't have a `test()` method to override and consequently you're writing code that should be in `Predicate` in each class. Basically, I suggest you change `Predicate` like,

```
public class Predicate
{
  public boolean test(int x) {
    return false;
  }
  public int countIF(int[] a) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int v : a) {
      if (test(x)) count++;
    }   
    return count;
  }
}
```

Then your `IsEven` (for example),

```
public class IsEven extends Predicate
{
  public boolean test(int x) {
    return ((x%2)==0);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Elloitt Thanks for your your help. I have made the relevant changes to my predicate class and the IsEven and IsNegative classes.I however cannot relate the countIF method in the Predicate class to the countIF method in the Count class. Shouldn't they have a relationship? Currently, the countIF method in my Count class has no relationship with the one in the Predicate class. I am lost. Can you please clarify that aspect for me please?

Comment: Why do you need the other `countIF`? This one is meant to replace it. If you need a `countIF` in `Count` you can delegate to the `Predicate.countIF()`.